# Flutter drag scroll behaviour not working on web after 2.5 update

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just upgraded Flutter from 2.2 to 2.5, but my web app is behaving differently.
In 2.2 it was possible to scroll vertically in a SingleChildScrollView and horizontally in a TabBarView **by dragging** without additional code. Dragging doesn't do anything now.

I would like to revert to the original behaviour from 2.2. Dragging should scroll vertically and horizontally.

However, adding different ScrollPhysics to those two widgets does not have any effect.
I have found solutions that recommend wrapping the widget in a GestureDetector. This leads to a lot boilerplate code. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can revert back to the previous version of Flutter.

Comment: @Apealed Reverting to an old version forever is not a good idea. You would miss any future optimization and security updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Flutter 2.5 Summary***

> ScrollBehaviors now allow or disallow drag scrolling from specified
> PointerDeviceKinds. ScrollBehavior.dragDevices, by default, allows
> scrolling widgets to be dragged by all PointerDeviceKinds except for
> PointerDeviceKind.mouse.

```
// Set ScrollBehavior for an entire application.
MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
  // ...
);
```

```
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

Referrence: [Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)